# PowerShell: determine if a remote server is part of a NLB cluster

Tags: windows, powershell, cluster-computing, nlb

As the title says, I'm looking for a way of determining if a given Windows server is part of a NLB cluster.
I know that it is possible to check the presence of a service with Get-Service... but NLB is a kernel driver... also how do I deal with older Windows versions such as 2003?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for win2008+ you have possibility to use Get-NlbClusterNode cmdlet.
I believe you can also check win2003 servers via [NLB WMI class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),  unfortunately I dont have any 2003 server to check if I'm right.

Comment: Thanks, how would that WMI query look like? And can it be safely used for all versions of Windows Server?
I can test it ASAP.

Comment: @PowerShellEnthusiast I believe its pretty safe, we just querying WMI. 

Get-WmiObject -Class MicrosoftNLB_Node -computername $servername -namespace root\MicrosoftNLB | Select-Object __Server, statuscode

Comment: Thanks again, I'm testing it.

Comment: Tested against a Windows Server 2008 R2 cluster, works great.
This cluster has 2nodes and I'm getting the status codes 0 and 1008, no idea what they represent.
I actually don't think I have a 2003 cluster to test against, but I'm sure it would work.